# How to connect to remote mysql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I have a website and a database on a host. But I want the administrator panel on my laptop? Is it possible connect remotely? How can I do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Have a local copy of the database?  You need to give us more information!

Comment: I think he wants to have local phpmyadmin that will connect to remote db

Comment: Are you simply asking if you can have something like PhpMyAdmin on your laptop while your database sits on a server?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly your question, you're looking for a GUI front-end for a remote MySQL database. There's many MySQL front-ends out there, but two I would recommend are the official [MySQL Workbench](http://mysql.com/products/workbench/) if you're running Windows or Linux, and [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) if you're running Mac (MySQL Workbench can also run on Mac, but I personally prefer Sequel Pro). Both are free.

Comment: I'm looking a way to connect to database via php...from my laptop to my server.

Comment: Why does it have to be via PHP? If you just need to administer the server, there's no reason to set up PHP on your local machine as well, you can just use a standalone program like the ones I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should try is simply connecting to the remote MySQL server by the command line.

`$ mysql -u your_user -h remote.host.name -p`

Depending on the output will determine what you need to do next.

**Error 1**

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'remote.host.name' (113)`

This means that the port is not even open for an external machine to connect to it, so you will need to add whatever port MySQL is running on to your firewall to accept incoming connections.

**Error 2**

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'your_user'@'your.host.name' (using password: YES)`

Assuming that your login credentials are correct, this means that you need to grant permissions from within MySQL. Connecting locally from the remote server, grant permissions like this:

`GRANT ALL ON your_database.* TO your_user@'your.host.name' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';`

Obviously substitute all of the relevant things to what they should be.

When you can connect by command line, connecting by PHP is as simple as using the hostname, username and password information that you used in the `mysql` command above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a piece of software called Chive to do this, however it's possible that your server doesn't accept connections remotely.

You can either install Chive locally on your machine and connect to the remote computer, or install Chive remotely and connect to it via HTTP (though I strongly recommend HTTPS).

http://www.chive-project.com/

Answer (score 0):

Wow, just like you connect to the site, you should only change the authentication data if necessary, and external IP mysql.